# How can I combine multiple CAKeyframeAnimations into single keyframe animation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

Say I want to combine `transform`

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
   animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
```

and `opacity`

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
   animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
```

into keyframe animation. How do I combine and specify transform/opacity values for each keyframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two animations just like you do, use the same `keyTimes` for both of them, and add them both to the layer with `addAnimation:forKey:`. It's that easy.

Comment: I thought they would get out of sync sooner or later since they don't know about each other... is it really best way?

Comment: Is it possible/better to use `CAAnimationGroup` to combine multiple CAKeyframeAnimation?

Comment: Sure, group them with CAAnimationGroup, that's better if you have more animations. CAAnimationGroup works only with one layer, so if you do animations with more layers, group those with CATransaction.

Comment: Anyway, there's always a CATransaction setup in main thread, so even if you do not group animations in any way, they will be grouped. Grouping is required only if you create more animations, each with different properties like timing...

Comment: Here's some documentation that describes this in detail:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#
scroll down to 'Animating Multiple Changes Together'